# Testrpc Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8545 on Mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, command-line-interface, ethereum

I am getting an error when running `testrpc`

What may be the problem and how may I solve this?

```
EthereumJS TestRPC v6.0.3 (ganache-core: 2.0.2)
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:74143
var Module;if(!Module)Module=(typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:null)||{};var moduleOverrides={};for(var key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=false;if(Module["ENVIRONMENT"]){if(Module["ENVIRONMENT"]==="WEB"){ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=true}else if(Module["ENVIRONMENT"]==="WORKER"){ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=true}else if(Module["ENVIRONMENT"]==="NODE"){ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=true}else if(Module["ENVIRONMENT"]==="SHELL"){ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=true}else{throw new Error("The provided Module['ENVIRONMENT'] value is not valid. It must be one of: WEB|WORKER|NODE|SHELL.")}}else{ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&"function"==="function"&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;ENVIRONMENT_IS_

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8545
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1351:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1476:7)
    at Server.server.listen (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:106030:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:50244:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:21:30)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:64:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:67:10)
```

Comment: Running more than one instance?

Answer (score 2):

Another process is already using the port 8545. Simply find the PID using the corresponding port and kill it:

```
lsof -i:8545
kill -9 PID
```